# Suppose u and v both denote sets in Python. Under what condition can we guarantee that u|v == u^v?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I'm stuck in below
 question plz explain it.
Suppose u and v both denote sets in Python.  Under what condition can we guarantee that u|v == u^v?

I have tried by considering set values as 1,2,3 & 4,5,6.I'm getting answer as v should be subset of u.likewise what should be the correct condition

Comment: What have you considered so far?

Comment: For a given x, what does it mean for x to be in u|v? What does it mean for x to be in u^v?

Answer (score 2):

> In order for **u - (u-v) == v** to be true;  The set **v** should be a
>   subset of the set **u**.

Example:

```
u = {1,2,3,4}
v = {3,4}  # Here, v is a subset of u
u-v = {1,2}
u - (u-v) = {3,4} == v # Hence, proved!
```

Comment: No. Your condition don't need be fulfilled.  Other possibility is that the set `u` is a subset of the set `v`.

Comment: How ? 
can you elaborate please ?

It dint seem so:

Example:

u = {1,2}
v = {1,2,3,4}  # Here, u is a subset of v

u-v = {}

u - (u-v) = {1,2} != v      `so the condition doesnt gets satisfied here`

Comment: I didn't wrote about your complicated equation (more complicated that OP question) but about your sentence *"The set v should be a subset of the set u."* And it is obviously wrong as both operators `|` and `^` are symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

The necessary and sufficient condition is:

```
The sets are disjunct.
```

(i. e. they have no common member.)

To your second question, x to be in u^v means that

```
x belongs to one and only one of the two sets
```

(i. e. it belongs to one, but *not* to other.)

Answer (score 0):

For two distinct sets A and B the `|` operator denotes the union which gives a new set with elements from both A and B and `^` which is symmetric difference will give you a set with elements in either A or B but not both. Thus, these operators return equal result if two sets A and B haven't any common item. In other word they shouldn't have any intersection.

Here is an example:

```
In [13]: a = {1, 2}

In [14]: b = {3, 4, 7}

In [15]: a^b == a|b
Out[15]: True

In [16]: b = {3, 4, 7, 1}

In [17]: a^b == a|b
Out[17]: False
```

Comment: similarly for  u - (u - v) == v? will apply same condition?

Comment: @Aishwarya This is just another equation with another proof.

Comment: @Aishwarya Welcome. You can also tell this to community by accepting the answer.